Prune my Maple tree
Last year it got hit by lightning and severed about 25% in the middle. This year we had 90 mile an hour straight winds that took half of the tree. I don't think my son or my husband did it the proper way. I want to save it. HELP PLEASE.


Your Trident Maple is not dying. Yoiu don't think my son or my husband did it the proper way. Did what? If they already pruned it, show us. Most handy gardeners and local nurseries will know what to do. Luckily it's very accessible.

The branch that has split off needs to be removed. You can't save it. The normal method is to cut a notch from below, then cut it from top. Otherwise the weight of the branch will tear down a gash on the main trunk or perl a chunk of bark off.
If its really precious then call an arborist.

Just to add: do it as soon as possible. The weight of broken branch will deep the cut, which it is bad.
